# How might I mount an iso into a virtual CD drive with VBoxManage "No bootable option or device was found." (virtualbox)?

Tags: command-line, virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization

Following script, `create-windows-11.sh`, is meant to

1. Create `win11.vdi` out of  `Win11_23H2_English_x64v2.iso`
2. Create a Windows 11 virtual machine.
3. Mount Win11_23H2_English_x64v2.iso into `win11.vdi`.
4. Start this VM so that I can proceed with launching Windows 11.

```
#!/bin/bash

nm=w11
img_dr="/home/joan/VirtualBox VMs/Win11_23H2_English_x64v2.iso"
of=win11.vdi
VBoxManage convertfromraw "$img_dr" "$of" --format=VDI && echo -e "Proceeding with createvm"
VBoxManage createvm -n "$nm" -d --ostype=Windows11_64 -r 
echo "Let's start $nm."
VBoxManage startvm "$nm"
VBoxManage showvminfo "$nm"
```

Running `create-windows-11.sh` gives me the following output:

```
Converting from raw image file="/home/joan/VirtualBox VMs/Win11_23H2_English_x64v2.iso" to file="win11.vdi"...
Creating dynamic image with size 6812706816 bytes (6498MB)...
Proceeding with createvm
Virtual machine 'w11' is created and registered.
UUID: 77ef158d-0d48-4561-bbdd-c7a0f4e2d6fb
Settings file: '/home/joan/VirtualBox VMs/w11/w11.vbox'
Let's start w11.
Waiting for VM "w11" to power on...
VM "w11" has been successfully started.
Name:                        w11
Encryption:     disabled
Groups:                      /
Guest OS:                    Windows 11 (64-bit)
UUID:                        77ef158d-0d48-4561-bbdd-c7a0f4e2d6fb
Config file:                 /home/joan/VirtualBox VMs/w11/w11.vbox
Snapshot folder:             /home/joan/VirtualBox VMs/w11/Snapshots
Log folder:                  /home/joan/VirtualBox VMs/w11/Logs
Hardware UUID:               77ef158d-0d48-4561-bbdd-c7a0f4e2d6fb
Memory size:                 4096MB
Page Fusion:                 disabled
VRAM size:                   128MB
CPU exec cap:                100%
HPET:                        disabled
CPUProfile:                  host
Chipset:                     piix3
Firmware:                    EFI
Number of CPUs:              2
PAE:                         disabled
Long Mode:                   enabled
Triple Fault Reset:          disabled
APIC:                        enabled
X2APIC:                      disabled
Nested VT-x/AMD-V:           disabled
CPUID Portability Level:     0
CPUID overrides:             None
Boot menu mode:              message and menu
Boot Device 1:               Floppy
Boot Device 2:               DVD
Boot Device 3:               HardDisk
Boot Device 4:               Not Assigned
ACPI:                        enabled
IOAPIC:                      enabled
BIOS APIC mode:              APIC
Time offset:                 0ms
BIOS NVRAM File:             /home/joan/VirtualBox VMs/w11/w11.nvram
RTC:                         local time
Hardware Virtualization:     enabled
Nested Paging:               enabled
Large Pages:                 enabled
VT-x VPID:                   enabled
VT-x Unrestricted Exec.:     enabled
AMD-V Virt. Vmsave/Vmload:   enabled
IOMMU:                       None
Paravirt. Provider:          Default
Effective Paravirt. Prov.:   HyperV
State:                       running (since 2023-12-22T08:21:52.671000000)
Graphics Controller:         VBoxSVGA
Monitor count:               1
3D Acceleration:             disabled
2D Video Acceleration:       disabled
Teleporter Enabled:          disabled
Teleporter Port:             0
Teleporter Address:          
Teleporter Password:         
Tracing Enabled:             disabled
Allow Tracing to Access VM:  disabled
Tracing Configuration:       
Autostart Enabled:           disabled
Autostart Delay:             0
Default Frontend:            
VM process priority:         default
Storage Controllers:
#0: 'SATA', Type: IntelAhci, Instance: 0, Ports: 2 (max 30), Bootable
NIC 1:                       MAC: 08002791CD25, Attachment: NAT, Cable connected: on, Trace: off (file: none), Type: 82540EM, Reported speed: 0 Mbps, Boot priority: 0, Promisc Policy: deny, Bandwidth group: none
NIC 1 Settings:  MTU: 0, Socket (send: 64, receive: 64), TCP Window (send:64, receive: 64)
NIC 2:                       disabled
NIC 3:                       disabled
NIC 4:                       disabled
NIC 5:                       disabled
NIC 6:                       disabled
NIC 7:                       disabled
NIC 8:                       disabled
Pointing Device:             USB Tablet
Keyboard Device:             PS/2 Keyboard
UART 1:                      disabled
UART 2:                      disabled
UART 3:                      disabled
UART 4:                      disabled
LPT 1:                       disabled
LPT 2:                       disabled
Audio:                       enabled (Driver: Default, Controller: HDA, Codec: STAC9221)
Audio playback:              enabled
Audio capture:               disabled
Clipboard Mode:              disabled
Drag and drop Mode:          disabled
Session name:                GUI/Qt
Video mode:                  0x0x0 at 0,0 enabled
VRDE:                        disabled
OHCI USB:                    disabled
EHCI USB:                    disabled
xHCI USB:                    enabled
USB Device Filters:          <none>
Available remote USB devices: <none>
Currently attached USB devices: <none>
Bandwidth groups:            <none>
Shared folders:              <none>
VRDE Connection:             not active
Clients so far:              0
Recording enabled:           no
Recording screens:           1
 Screen 0:
    Enabled:                 yes
    ID:                      0
    Record video:            yes
    Destination:             File
    File:                    /home/joan/VirtualBox VMs/w11/w11-screen0.webm
    Options:                 vc_enabled=true,ac_enabled=false,ac_profile=med
    Video dimensions:        1024x768
    Video rate:              512kbps
    Video FPS:               25fps
* Guest:
Configured memory balloon:   0MB
OS type:                     Windows11_64
Additions run level:         0
Guest Facilities:            <none>
```

In VirtualBox's GUI I get:

```
BdsDxe: No bootable option or device was found.
BdsDxe: Press any key to enter the Boot Manager Menu
```

Do I get this message because I haven't let the VBoxManage know about the choice of `win11.vdi` as the virtual hard disk for this VM?
How might I configure that? How might I mount the iso into a virtual CD drive with VBoxManage?

P.S. For the sake of automation, I would like to limit the scope of this question to `VBoxManage`. If possible, I would like to do in GUI as little as possible and solve everything with `VBoxManage`. My OS is Ubuntu Desktop 22.04 LTS.

Comment: Why on earth would you want to convert an install medium to a vdi? normally you create a new vdi, mount the iso, and boot that setup so the iso can install to the new vdi.

Comment: @LPChip Thanks for your worthy comment - I already modified my question in response to it. *create a new vdi, mount the iso, and boot that setup so the iso can install to the new vdi* - this is exactly what I want to accomplish with `VBoxManage`.

Comment: The correct terminology would be: `Create a win11.vdi and mount Win11_23H2_English_x64v2.iso into a virtual CD drive`. I don't know how to do this using vboxmanage though, so I can't assist you with the question itself, only help you understand what the question is so others can help you.

Comment: In either case, your .sh script is still converting so that's the first problem. It should create a new, empty vdi.

Comment: @LPChip `VBoxManage convertfromraw` command has misleading name. Despite its name the command actually creates a new vdi in the same directory as iso, leaving the latter intact.

Comment: Ah okay. So what you need next is find out what command you need to modify the VM and add the ISO as bootable device.